# owerride native javascript prototype, good or bad idea to performances?

Tags: javascript, performance, overriding, prototype

I know add function to prototype doesn't cost more memory usage, prototype are share to all instances. So ok for memory but, what about global time to create instance ? Load functions's index at each new Object cost more time if the functions's index is bigger, no?

**Add lot of functions in Object prototype, it will decrease global performances ?**

For exemple, if I want add all functions of http://underscorejs.org lib directly in prototype of Object or Array, to write `myObject.where(...)` insteadof `_.where(myObject, ...)`
**it was good or bad practice ?**

Comment: *"it was good or bad practice ?"* is primarily opinion-based and thus off-topic for SO.

Comment: Bad practice, but will probably not affect performance.

Comment: there is a reason why underscore is not mutating `Object` ...

Comment: Also, performance can be measured as well. What kind of help do you need?

Comment: @JonasW. I want to know why it's a bad idea to override Object directly ?

Comment: It’s a bad idea because it doesn’t extend to more than one module. Library sets `Object.prototype.where` one way, application sets it another, one of them breaks. Such extensions are as hard to keep track of as globals, and not worth it when calling functions is so easy.

Comment: `1..where("does this come from??")`

Comment: but all modules are scoped, and nobody create module with override native prototype, so conflict will never come in reality no?

Answer (score 2):

> So ok for memory but, what about global time to create instance ? Load functions's index at each new Object cost more time if the functions's index is bigger, no?

No. When a new instance is created, it doesn't get a copy of everything on its prototype, it gets a reference to its prototype. So the number of properties on its prototype has no effect whatsoever on the time required to create an instance.

That is, we start (upon global initialization) with something like this in memory (ignoring a lot of details):

```
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−+          
Object−−−−−−−−−−>| (function) |          
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−+          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 | prototype  |−−−−−−−−−>|    (object)    |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−+          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                         | hasOwnProperty |
                                         | toString       |
                                         | valueOf        |
                                         | ...            |
                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

then if we do this:

```
var o = {};
```

...we have something like this:

```
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−+          
Object−−−−−−−−−−>| (function) |          
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−+          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 | prototype  |−−−−−+−−−>|    (object)    |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                    |    | hasOwnProperty |
                                    |    | toString       |
                                    |    | valueOf        |
                                    |    | ...            |
                                    |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
o−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|   (object)    |  |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                 | [[Prototype]] |−−+
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

---

> For exemple, if I want add all functions of http://underscorejs.org lib directly in prototype of `Object` or `Array`, to write `myObject.where(...)` insteadof `_.where(myObject, ...)`
>   it was good or bad practice ?

Whether it's good or bad practice is a matter of opinion and thus off-topic for SO. There are some objective issues to consider:

- If you do, you **must** make the new properties non-enumerable (via `Object.definedPropety`) so they don't show up in `for-in` and `Object.keys`; otherwise, you'll break a lot of thinsg.
- If JavaScript gets a standard `where`, you suddenly have a conflict to deal with.
- If you use a library that accepts objects with optional features, one of which happens to be called `where`, and you pass an object to that library, the library will assume that `where` is the one it's looking for.

Answer (score -2):

A debate as old as time. Performance wise, going with Class based and other prototypical inheritance methodologies can create side effects later on as your application scales. This, will effect performance. Also, extending the prototype in a classical inheritance situation means each new instance has to run up the prototype chain to execute, slowing down performance. Lodash and other utils are great helpers but I try avoiding them in production in favor of a more efficient vanilla solution that doesn't rely on more deps to bloat the code base. Factory functions offer an alternative to extending native JS objects, and since they are only functions, execution doesn't need to worry about building to the prototype. As such, you get a boost in performance. Also, the context of `this` is much simpler to preserve and you don't have to worry about stupid bugs when forgetting to write `new` in front of your class instance. ES6 introduced classes and many have many the jump to using them without questioning potential bottlenecks. It's not a black and white scenario. All about choosing the best solution that fits with your project needs.

Comment: *“Also, extending the prototype in a classical inheritance situation means each new instance has to run up the prototype chain to execute, slowing down performance.”* [citation needed] this is not true in modern JS engines

Comment: Factory function was an encapsulation? like jQuery? if not, can you give me an exemple to be sure I understand

Comment: I know of a few solid tuts out there but it's late and the mind is ready for some sleep. Here's a great article to get started: https://blog.risingstack.com/fundamental-node-js-design-patterns/
If I can find the old material I used way back when to learn this stuff, I'll shoot it your way. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.